# Setting dropdown menu width

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to change the Country dropdown menu on this page:

http://www.chasewatts.com/free-signup

I just want it to be the same width as the other lines (80%) but nothing I do seems to change that.  Can you not change the width of dropdowns using a CSS file?

This is the code for that line in my .tpl file:

```
<tr><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareaemail}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.email}{else}<input type="text" name="email" tabindex="4" style="width:80%;" value="{$clientsdetails.email}" />{/if}</td><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareacountry}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.country}{else}{$clientcountrydropdown|replace:'<select':'<select tabindex="12"'}{/if}</td></tr>
```

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can offer!

Answer (score 0):

```
.selectboxit-container .selectboxit-options{
width:330px;}
```